# Second camera does not show UI Image element (but does show sprite)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity 2D board game similar to WordFeud: a gameboard with tiles (UI Image prefabs generated with code), with underneath the board a user interface with draggable tiles, buttons, scores etc. I want to zoom in on the game board by double tap on the screen. 
The game scales with the device resolution using the canvas scaler option as demonstrated here:[Charger Games](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rld_3SgrZw4). For the zoom I have added a second camera that renders its output to a render texture as explained here:[Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/PiotrSobolewski/20160512/272600/Implementing_a_minimap_in_Unity_tutorial.php). The render texture will eventually take the position of the game board. In the example screens attached it is a bit smaller than the full board to show what's happening.

In the trial setup I am able to perform the zoom with the second camera on a sprite (dragged to the scene) but the second camera fails to render a UI Image element if added to the scene. Yet this is what my game is composed of: UI Image elements.

Question: how do I get the second camera to show UI Image elements on the render texture?

Attached an image with combined screen dumps of the setup.[image: Test screens] From left to right: 1) the main canvas with the scaler enabled (it uses the UI image - game board to fill the background), 2) second camera setup (note that camera preview shows the Wordfeud sprite, but not the UI Image test), 3) params of WordFeud sprite, 4) params of UI Image test, 5) params of RawImage - render texture (this is a child of Minimap canvas).

I does not matter if I put the sprite or the UI Image in the default layer or the UI layer, the result in both cases is the same: the sprite is rendered, the UI Image is not.

Unity version 5.3.3.f1

Comment: UI Elements as an overlay belong to a Canvas; that canvas usually belongs to a camera. When you start looking through a different camera the UI may not be visible at all or scaled differently. Also check depth coordinates of the object that is missing in relation to the depth of the second camera.

Comment: @Jeroen: the UI Element is seen by the Main camera (though not rendered in camera preview), so following your reasoning, the main / 1st Canvas belongs to the main camera. There is another thing: if I set the main Canvas to Worldspace (instead of Screen space overlay) the UI Element is seen by the second camera! (however scaling now fails etc.). Depth main cam is -1, depth 2nd cam is 0 (see pic), so that should be ok.

Comment: Do assign an event camera to the worldspace canvas, otherwise it uses `Camera.main` to figure out what camera to use, and `Camera.main` is just a shortcut for `GameObject.FindObjectWithTag("main_camera")` which is slow.  You'll see a noticeable increase in performance on mobile by setting that field yourself in the inspector.